# Python Requests TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror

I'm using Python requests module, but I'm in a trouble. 
I'm trying to do a request, this is the code:

```
params = {"user_id":"1234567890", "api":"API-KEY"}
method = 'getUserStatus'
requests.get("https://www.example.com/“ % method, params)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Thanks for reply,
Marco

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18053555/5272003

Comment: `requests.post('https://api.iata.ovh/{0}.format(method), params)`

Comment: @NikhilParmar I get this: http://pastebin.com/MCa3meg1

Comment: That is a separate problem which can be solve using -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/31678467/5272003

Comment: @NikhilParmar I'm on Mac OS X, how I can fix it?

Comment: And I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: First you need to accept the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123065/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-marcobuster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code with right formatting - 
`requests.post('https://api.iata.ovh/{0}.format(method), params)`