# requests.exceptions.SSLError

Tags: python, macos, python-requests, pyopenssl

I have `fiddle.py` containing 4 lines

```
import requests

url = "https://randomuser.me/api/"
locations = requests.get(url,verify=False).json()

print locations
```

When I run it, I kept getting

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)

---

**Try #1**

Set `verify=False`

Run the code, Same Error.

---

**Try #2**

Run `sudo pip install --upgrade requests`

Run the code, same error.

---

**Try #3**

Run

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

and

`sudo pip install requests[security]`

Run the code, different error.

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)

---

## Details

- Python 2.7.10
- OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
- Mac OS X 10.11.6

How can I debug this?

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649390/python-requests-ssl-handshake-failure

Comment: I've tried all of them, do I need to restart my Mac or Terminal ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issues.

Answer (score 3):

You want to be on OpenSSL 1.0.2 and python 2.7.12.  You will probably also want the latest curl.

```
brew update
brew upgrade openssl
brew upgrade curl
brew upgrade python

python --version # make sure you have python 2.7.12
curl https://randomuser.me/api/ # to verify
```

Comment: You may need that `--force-link`, too. I don't use Brew, so I'm not sure if that's what its called. But it shows up often for Mac, Brew and OpenSSL questions.

Comment: Even my python now is 2.7.12 - I got this `curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure` when I run this `curl https://randomuser.me/api/`

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: @ihue:  what is the output of `curl --version`?

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure they are running on port 443 for https and you are not getting a redirect if on Linux you can use `dig +short example.com` I ran into the same issue on google hosted sites, with that command if it is google hosted you should get an output similar to `ghs.googlehosted.com` or the redirected url in this case I believe google hosted sites will redirect due to a Web application Firewall. When I attempt to visit the url that I get the error on from the `requests.get(domain)` I get redirected to login portal