# python urllib2.py urlopen is causing SSL routine SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python, ssl

The issue is that i am getting is from within python, using the urllib2 library.

The exact error I am getting is:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno1] _ssl.c:499: error:14077410:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure>
```

I am not sure what I should do to resolve it on my end since I am just using a library.  I didnt know if the urllib2 library located at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html has some flags I could use to circumvent this error.

Right now I am using it in the following call:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

url = "https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-2017.1.2.exe";
u = urlopen(url)
meta = u.info()
```

As you can see, i am trying to automate a script for environment setup, leveraging JetBrain's community edition IDE... which will be the default install unless the user specifies something else.

[image: Image of stack trace]

Comment: I would use the `requests` package, makes life much more enjoyable

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649390/python-requests-ssl-handshake-failure

Comment: Since the server requires SNI but looks fine apart from this I've marked this as duplicate of a question which has exactly this problem with SNI enabled servers. If you feel that this is not a duplicate please provide the version of Python and the OpenSSL used in Python so one can see that it is not the same problem and can further debug it.

Comment: @reptilicus so when i run initialization on my application, just check if requests exists, if not just pip install it via `pip install requests[security]` ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ill have to follow up though with my other machine, as my windows machine is what got the error.