# Python requests gets TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

I am trying to  connect to a website with `requests` that requires using a client certificate.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, cert='path to cert')
print(r.status_code)
```

This works for one site that uses the same client cert. That server is using `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS 1.0`. However my target site uses `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS 1.1`. So basically the difference is TLS 1 works and TLS 1.1 doesn't. Everything works fine in browser so it must have something to do with Python's SSL.

I am using `requests` version 2.7.0 and I have `requests[security]` installed as well. `pip freeze`:

```
cffi==0.9.2
cryptography==0.8.1
ndg-httpsclient==0.3.3
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycparser==2.10
pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
requests==2.7.0
six==1.9.0
```

The specific error I am getting is `requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:600)`. This is on Windows 7 with Python 3.4.3. Unfortunately this is on an internal machine so I am stuck with Windows and our internal mirror of PyPi does not have the latest versions of everything. It seems to me like this has something to do with `ssl` failing and not necessarily `requests`.

Google does not give back promising results. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857889/ssl-error-using-python-requests-to-access-shibboleth-authenticated-server) StackOverflow post that describes the same problem, but the solution provided (using a custom adapter) does not work for me.

Hopefully someone else has run into this before and can give me some tips on how to fix it. Please and thanks.

EDIT: I did a wireshark capture of the interaction. The SSL alert sent back is "Level: Fatal (2) Description: Internal Error (80)". After the TCP connection start, my machine sends a client hello.

```
Content Type: Handshake (22)
Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
Length: 512
```

Then the handshake protocol segment of that packet is

```
Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
Length: 508
Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0301)
```

followed by a list of the supported cipher suites, etc. I looked in the list of cipher suites sent by my client and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` is listed. The server ACKs this message then sends the Alert packet.

Comment: Can you capture a trace of the network traffic with Wireshark?  What are all the parameters of the SSL negotiation during the handshake before the alert is sent?

Comment: I'll edit with the results now

Comment: @AdamRosenfield posted

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of an identical `SSLError` by removing the first entry `ECDH+AESGCM` from `requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS`, with which the server seemed to have problems. The line

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5'
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me,   `request.request('GET'...`   instead of  `request.get(...`  works.

Answer (score -1):

And I got rid of the above SSLError by removing almost all the first entry:

> requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5'